# Implementing sample code for authenticating to Gmail with OAuth2

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I use code from [this link](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools) to access gmail imap server, because I could not find Android-friendly port of javamail with OAUTH support (javamail 1.5.2 or higher).

However, the problem with this code:

```
public static IMAPStore connectToImap(String host, int port, String userEmail, String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
    props.put(OAuth2SaslClientFactory.OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP, oauthToken);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
    IMAPSSLStore store = new IMAPSSLStore(session, unusedUrlName);
    final String emptyPassword = "";
    store.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);
    return store;
}
```

is that a new Store object is created every time auth token is changed (expires). And then I have to create a new Folder and read my messages again...

**My question is:**

Is it possible to change auth token without creating a new `Store` object? I would like to be able to implement something like

```
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, oauth2_access_token)
```

(example from javamail 1.5.2) to reconnect, without the need to recreate the `Store` object.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the expiration of the auth token causing your active connection to be dropped?  If you need to create a new connection with the same Store you should be able to set the property to a new value and make a new connection, without creating a new Store object.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. To reconnect using same Store object and new auth token. But how to do it (auth token is set in Properties object), following the posted code?

Comment: Call props.put again with the new token.

Comment: But then I have to create a new Session object in order to apply new properties, right? And a new Store obj in order to apply new session?

Comment: No, the Session keeps a reference to your Properties object, it doesn't make a copy of it.

Comment: In that case, please post a formal answer, so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a new connection with the same Store you should be able to set the property to a new value and make a new connection, without creating a new Store object.  Just call props.put with the new value.  The Session keeps a reference to the Properties object rather than making a copy of it.

Comment: Thanks Bill, is that behaviour specified?

Comment: No, I don't believe it is.